# When moving the object along a given axis, the coordinates change along others axes

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a problem that I can not understand. When moving the object along an axis x, y or z, the coordinates are changed simultaneously along others axes. Here is my file [blender](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40820)

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to have a full screenshot of the Blender window, on the one hand, and a copy of your ~.blend file uploaded to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or comparable facility, on the other.

Comment: @brasshat, I have added my blender file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40820

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates you're reading are referred to the bone's local space: if your bone were exactly aligned to the world coordinates (in edit mode, during the rigging) you would have your translation matching; if, more commonly, the bone is oblique, a translation along one axis is, relative to the bone local space, a movement along more than one axis.
This is the reason why it's common, during rigging, add "extra control" bones aligned to the world coordinates, to act as parents of real control bones, making editing easier, expecially with the graph editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your object seems to be parented to some other object, or at least using some sort of constraints.
Even though visually it moves only along the Z axis internally Blender is probably trying to solve all the constraints thus resulting in motion in more than one axis, I think.